# javascript: passing as object or function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, frameworks

My question is rather weird, it has to do with something i have seen in jQuery but so far i have been unable to recreate it.

in jQuery you can go like this

```
jQuery('div').append
```

or

```
jQuery.ajax
```

the application i am making would need a similar syntax, i notice if you use new like

```
var that=new function(){
}
```

you can call the function with just that, without the (), but in some cases i would need it.

The reason for this is some functions i have need to select a dom element just like jQuery so.

```
that('[data-something="this"]').setEvent('click',functin(){})
```

and some automatically do it so:

```
that.loadIt('this','[data-something="that"]')
```

the reason for this is that the dom elements are loaded externally and pushed, then the script waits for it to be ready before continuing. and doing it this way, to me anyway seems like the most cleanest way to get this functionality (i am coding a full javascript framework so i avoid libraries to keep the scripts fast)

Comment: Functions *are* objects in javascript. So, nothing is stopping them from having properties attached to them as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions are objects.

Just get rid of `new`, and add properties directly to `that`.

```
var that = function() {
    // do some work
}

that.loadit = function() {
    // do other work
}
```

Since you're trying to achieve something like jQuery does, then have `that` call a constructor.

```
;(function(global) {

       // function to be publicly exposed
    var that = function(foo, bar) {
        return new MyLibrary(foo, bar);
    }

       // publicly expose the function
    global.that = that;

       // use the function as a namespace for utilities
    that.loadit = function() {
        // do other work
    }

       // The actual constructor function, like the internal jQuery constructor
    MyLibrary(foo, bar) {
        // constructor function
    }

       // Prototypal inheritance of objects created from the constructor
    MyLibrary.prototype.setEvent = function() {
        // do some work
        return this;  // allows for method chaining
    };
    MyLibrary.prototype.otherMethod = function() {
        // do something else
        return this;  // allows for method chaining
    };
})(this);
```

Answer (score 5):

Functions are objects and can have properties, just like other objects can.  So, you can add a property to a function like this:

```
function myFunc(){}
myFunc.someFunc = function(){}
```

If you use `new myFunc` the resulting object won't have `someFunc` as it's not part of the `prototype`.

So, you can make something like this:

```
function myFunc(){
    // This lets you do "myFunc()" instead of "new myFunc()"
    if (!(this instanceof myFunc)) {
        return new myFunc();
    }
    else{
        this.val = 0;

        this.setVal = function(x){
            this.val = x;
            // for function chaining
            return this;
        }

        this.getVal = function(){
            return this.val;
        }
    }
}

// This function is not part of the prototype
myFunc.test = function(){
    alert('hi');
}

// Some tests
var obj = myFunc();
obj.setVal(12).getVal(); // 12

myFunc.test();

obj.test(); // Error: 'test' is not a function

myFunc.getVal(); // Error: 'getVal' is not a function
```

Comment: so both myFunc().someFunc() and myFunc.someFunc() will work? ill give that a shot and see how it goes ^^

Comment: @user1666672 myFunc().someFunc() will call someFUnc as an instance method of what ever myFunc returns whereas myFunc.someFunc() will call the instance method called someFunc of the object identified by myFunc (an object in this case representing a function but that's irrelevant it could be any object)

Comment: @user1666672: Not quite.  In the example: `myFunc().getVal()` will work, but `myFunc.getVal()` won't.  Conversely, `myFunc.test()` will work, but `myFunc().test()` won't.

Comment: be aware that using constructor functions are dangerous. (and they are by convention named with a Capital starting letter). If you call a constructor function without new your code will execute just fine but will not create a new object but instead alter the global object (this will represent the global object of you forget the new) this can be a real nightmare to debug

Comment: @RuneFS: What do you mean "alter the global object"?

Comment: If you call myFunc in a browser without using new then 'this' will refer to 'window' and the properties you are setting will be added to 'window'

Comment: @RuneFS: Oh, whoops.  Fixed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.loadIt=function(var1,var2) {
  // $(this) is automatically passed
  // do stuff
}
```

call it like this

```
$('#element').loadIt('a variable','another variable');
```

Comment: i need to clarify, i'm not using jQuery, just using it as an example as it uses similar syntax to what i need to create.

Comment: ah sorry, suppose I should have read a little more thoroughly.